# Image gallery swipe UI in MonoTouch

Tags: c#, iphone, ios, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I am looking to create a UI experience almost identical to swiping through images in the Camera Roll on the iPhone.  I have 5 images that I simply want to be able to swipe through.  This view will be the first view of a Tab Bar Controller that I have in place.  This is my first iPhone (iOS) app attempt so if anyone feels this question needs to be broken down into smaller chunks, please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Pagecontroller](http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/pagecontrol-example-in-iphone/).

In this example they have add label, instead of that you add your imageView.

EDIT:

For [Monotouch](http://simon.nureality.ca/simon-says-monotouch-scrolling-like-iphone-home-screen-in-c/).

Comment: Looking for a MonoTouch solution.

Comment: @KingofBliss: The MonoTouch link is dead.  Any idea where this content can be found now?

Comment: @JoshuaFrank The another answer has the link. The controls where developed by him. Thanks Eduardo Scoz. :)

Answer (score 4):

Here's an example of the paging control for MonoTouch I developed some time ago: https://github.com/escoz/monotouch-controls

Take a look at the PagedViewController. That code is actually used in my app, [Quicklytics](http://escoz.com/quicklytics).

Answer (score 0):

The Photos module of Nimbus is exactly what you are looking for.

http://docs.nimbuskit.info/NimbusPhotos.html

The MonoTouch bindings can be found here.

https://github.com/theonlylawislove/MonoTouch.Nimbus